# Parameterization Of A Cycloid

Tags: calculus

I need to find the length of $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=1$ which is said to be a Cycloid.

[There is an answer](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Length_of_Arc_of_Cycloid) fo for it but how did they get to the parameterization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [astroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid), not [cycloid](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Length_of_Arc_of_Cycloid) that you are quoting. You can find all that you need in Wiki and elswhere, it's a well known curve.

Astroid is the locus of a point on a circle as it rolls inside a fixed circle with four times the radius.

Cycloid is the curve traced by a point on a circle as it rolls along a straight line.